# ggplot2 odd results from geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate a conditional density plot as shown in the docs for [stat_density](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/stat_density.html), but I need to do it with ggplot and not qplot because I need to facet the plot.  However, my data has unequal numbers of rows in each facet, and when I plot it, I get weird results.  Here's an MRE:

```
test.df = data.frame(model=c(rep("A",100),rep("B",50),rep("C",20)),
as.factor(cnt=c(rbinom(100,1,0.5),rbinom(50,1,0.5),rbinom(20,1,0.5))),
xvar=c(seq(1,100),seq(1,50),seq(1,20)))

# This works fine, ignoring the model facets.
ggplot(test.df,aes(x=xvar,y=..count..,fill=cnt)) + geom_density(position="fill")

# Something's wrong with this one.
ggplot(test.df,aes(x=xvar,y=..count..,fill=cnt)) + geom_density(position="fill") + 
facet_wrap(~model)
```

Here's an example of what it looks like ignoring the model (and it looks the same if you subset and plot each group individually):

[image]

vs with faceting:

[image]

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

edit: this is with R 2.15.1 / Rstudio 0.97.314 under OSX 10.8.2, ggplot2 0.9.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems arise because it doesn't really make sense to estimate the density  when you are extrapolating the `x` variable. (the limits for model = B are [0,50], and for model=C are [0,20]

If you set `scales='free_x'` then you won't be forcing `ggplot` to do something silly.

```
ggplot(test.df,aes(x=xvar,y=..count..,fill=cnt)) + 
 geom_density(position = "fill") + 
 facet_wrap(~model,scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

You could alternatively pass `trim = TRUE` to `geom_density` (and thus `stat_density`), which would trim to the range of the observed data when calculating (and plotting) the densities

```
ggplot(test.df,aes(x=xvar,y=..count..,fill=cnt)) + 
 geom_density(position="fill",trim = TRUE) + 
 facet_wrap(~model)
```

[image]

Perhaps there should be some kind of warning regarding the nonsense results in the original attempt, but I think this may be covered by `fortune(15)`

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(15)
## It really is hard to anticipate just how silly users can be.
##   -- Brian D. Ripley
##   R-devel (October 2003)
```

Comment: Thanks, mnel!  This answer caught me off guard, because it seems like ggplot doesn't do that for all geoms.  For example, ggplot(test.df,aes(x=xvar,y=cnt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~model)  doesn't extrapolate the x variable.  Is there a way to know which geoms will do this?  (In any case, thanks for the help, you saved me a mighty headache).

Comment: Did anyone notice that the OP was sampling from a **binomial** distribution? There's no way geom_density() is appropriate for this type of problem, because it gives the illusion of continuity where none exists.

Comment: @Dennis -- good spotting - I think fortune(15) still applies.